# Joining two queries with MYSQL and dealing with dates

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two queries that return results from a set of horse races.

The first query from table 1 returns the fastest time a horse has run, prior to the current races.

The second queries returns the basic details of the race, like the race number and horse names.

Separately the two queries work fine, however when I attempt to join the tables the dates in table 1 are different and the query starts returning the fastest time a horse has raced and now includes the current race.

Query 1 - it returns the fastest time a horse has run.

```
SELECT
raceref,
  date,
  horse,

  (
    SELECT min(finale)
    FROM sectional
    WHERE horse = t.horse
      AND date < t.date
    ORDER BY date DESC

  ) AS min_time

FROM sectional t
group by horse, raceref
order by raceref
```

Query 2 - returns the basic details of the race.

```
SELECT raceref, date, horse

from
results

group by raceref, horse
```

This is my attempted join.

```
SELECT tab2.raceref, tab2.date, tab2.horse, tab1.min_time
from
(
SELECT
raceref,
  date,
  horse,
   (
    SELECT min(finale)
    FROM sectional
    WHERE horse = t.horse
      AND date < t.date
    ORDER BY date DESC

      ) AS min_time

FROM sectional t
group by horse, raceref
order by raceref
) as tab1

inner join

    (select raceref, date, horse

from
results

group by raceref, horse
) as tab2

on tab1.horse = tab2.horse

group by horse
order by raceref;
```

Here's a screenshot of the output.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTApc.png

The issue above is that the query now shows the min time a horse has run, however we shouldn't have a time in that column as effectively that is the first run a horse has had. So they should all be null until a horse races a second time.

As I understand it you can add some conditions to a join around the date, however I can't really find any examples that I can use to get it to suit this situation.

Here's an SQL Fiddle however there is only a limited amount of data so the results don't work that well but it still gives an idea.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0d4f2/3

If anyone can offer any assistance it would be much appreciated.

Comment: After a quick look dont see repeat horse name, So how you want to handle horse hasnt run second time? What is the difference between result and sectional? what is the relationship?

Comment: I keep reading your question and still feel there are some more information need it regarding your schema and exactly what result you hope to get.

Comment: Hey @JuanCarlosOropeza. Thanks for taking a look. I should have the horse name in both, that was just a typo in SO. Both results and sectional are just the results of the races. However I'm trying to show in the combined query, only old data (prior to the race date) from the sectional table, and the current data from the results table. Hopefully that makes sense. Like I mentioned the queries work separately - just not joined together.

Comment: Yes, i understand the query work separted, but dont understand how would you like to join. That is why you should explain what is happening.

Comment: Can you improve the data sample in your sqlFiddle? I think we need some duplicate horse to see what happen in those cases.

Comment: No problem @JuanCarlosOropeza. I'm not really sure of the join type. I've tried the different ones without success. I really just want to add the results I get from the min_time query (Query 1) to the output from Query 2, as a new column matched by horse name and raceref.

Comment: I just give you an answer, but your query2 doesnt make any sense, you do a `group by` but no use any aggregation function? This is the problem with MySQL allowing bad written `group by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query2 doesnt make sense but here is my answer.

```
SELECT tab2.raceref
    ,tab2.DATE
    ,tab2.horse
    ,tab1.min_time
FROM (
    SELECT raceref
        ,DATE
        ,horse
        ,(
            SELECT min(finale)
            FROM sectional
            WHERE horse = t.horse
                AND DATE < t.DATE
            ORDER BY DATE DESC
            ) AS min_time
    FROM sectional t
    GROUP BY horse
        ,raceref
    ORDER BY raceref
    ) AS tab1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT raceref
        ,DATE
        ,horse
    FROM results
    GROUP BY raceref
        ,horse
    ) AS tab2 
ON tab1.horse = tab2.horse
AND tab1.DATE = tab2.DATE   <= i think you only miss this 
ORDER BY raceref;
```

But I feel if you only use raceref also will be enough

```
ON tab1.raceref = tab2.raceref
```

Comment: That did the trick - now working perfectly. Just needed to match the dates also. Thank you so much for your time. I really appreciate it.